# quick rpm install

Tags: linux, rpm, percona

I am trying to install percona server. This is a test machine and installed packages do not really matter. What all I need to do is install percona mysql server.

http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.0/Percona-Server-5.0.90-21/RPM/rhel5/i386/

I downloaded and tried to install. I got several dependency issues.

```
# rpm -ivh Percona-SQL-server-50-5.0.90-b21.10.rhel5.i386.rpm
file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of Percona-SQL-server-50-5.0.90-b21.10.rhel5.i386 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.i686

# rpm -e mysql-libs-5.1.61-4.el6.i686
error: Failed dependencies:
        libmysqlclient.so.16 is needed by (installed) postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686
        libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) is needed by (installed) postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686
        mysql-libs is needed by (installed) postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686

# rpm -e postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686
error: package postfix-2:2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686 is not installed

# rpm -e postfix-2.6.6-2.2.el6_1.i686
error: Failed dependencies:
        /usr/sbin/sendmail is needed by (installed) cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.i686
        /usr/sbin/sendmail is needed by (installed) redhat-lsb-4.0-3.el6.i686
```

What is the quick way to install this package bypassing all dependency issues?

Comment: Are you running RHEL5 or RHEL6?  cat /etc/redhat-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ignore dependencies or just try to satisfy with random packages you find, you'll just find yourself in 'RPM hell.'  Just because it's an RPM doesn't mean it works with your distribution.  Percona does have a [yum repository](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/repositories:yum).  I suggest you follow those directions, assuming that you're using either CentOS or RedHat.  Then installing percona will be as easy as `yum install Percona-Server-server-51`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to download and install these packages: http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.0/LATEST/RPM/rhel6/i686/

It seems you are trying to install RHEL5 package to RHEL6 system. You can verify this by typing:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Comment: You also need to install them all from the same `rpm` command, not separately.

Answer (score 1):

problem 1

You are installing a rpm for 5.x on a 6.x system from what I can tell

problem 2 .. Install their yum repo and install that way

Follow the steps here

http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/repositories:yum

Answer (score 0):

try

```
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck Percona-SQL-server-50-5.0.90-b21.10.rhel5.i386.rpm
```

this should resolve required dependencies